# Strange value for the "this" object

Tags: javascript, function, this, ecmascript-5

Regarding this code:

```
var name = "Jaguar";
var car = {
  name:"Ferrari",
  getName:function(){
    return this.name;
  }
};

alert((car.getName = car.getName)());
```

The output is: `Jaguar`.

Why does `this` object correspond to `Window` and not the object contained in the `car` variable?

It seems that the fact to reassign the object's function to itself leads to lose the assignment of `this` to the object when the function is called...

I'm trying to guess: Does it exist a kind of mechanism (using variable or other) that keep an eye on the non-reassignement of an object's function so that if that situation happens, this mechanism would prevent the assignement of the `this` keyword as usual (as being equals to the object)?

Comment: You are effectively doing a `(function() { return this.name; })()`...

Comment: It is a limitation of javascript. which can be solved by storing `this` in a variable and using it wherever possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is fairly subtle: `this` in JavaScript is determined entirely by *how a function is called*. To have `this` set to `car` during the call to `getName`, you have to call `getName` immediately upon retrieving it from the `car` object, like this:

```
car.getName() // or
car["getName"]()
```

(Or via [`Function#call`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) or [`Function#apply`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3), which let you specify the value for `this` explicitly.)

What you're doing in your example is effectively this:

```
// Set f to the result of the assignment expression,
// which is a reference to the getName function
var f = (car.getName = car.getName);

// Call it (separately)
f();
```

...which is different. Functions called in that way get `this` set to the global object (`window`, in browsers). (Except in strict mode; in strict mode `this` would be `undefined`.)

More (from my anemic blog):

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

> Does it exist a kind of mechanism (using variable or other) that keep an eye on the non-reassignement of an object's function so that if that situation happens, this mechanism would prevent the assignement of the this keyword as usual (as being equals to the object)?

I'm not entirely sure I follow that question, but if you want to have a function that always has a preset `this` value, then yes, there are a couple of ways to do that.

One is to use the new ES5 function [`bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

```
var name = "Jaguar";
var car = {
  name: "Ferrari"
};
car.getName = function(){
  return this.name;
}.bind(car);
alert((car.getName = car.getName)()); // "Ferrari"
```

`bind` returns a function that always has `this` set to the argument you give it.

The other way is to use a closure. And in fact, you can create a `bind`-like function in ES3 very easily:

```
function pseudoBind(func, thisArg) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(thisArg, arguments);
    };
}
```

That doesn't do everything `bind` does, but it does the `this` part. Then you'd have:

```
var name = "Jaguar";
var car = {
  name: "Ferrari"
};
car.getName = pseudoBind(function(){
  return this.name;
}, car);
alert((car.getName = car.getName)()); // "Ferrari"
```

More on closures (again from the blog):

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

In a future spec, we'll be getting a declarative way of creating functions that have a preset `this` value (so-called "[arrow functions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:arrow_function_syntax)" because the syntax for them involves uses `=>` rather than the `function` keyword).

Comment: Nice answer :) But one question:  what do you think about the statement:  (car.getName)() .Why doesn't it behave similarly as (car.getName = car.getName)()? Indeed, it would be similar as these both statements: var f = (car.getName); f();  but this case well returns Ferrari ...

Comment: @Mik378: `(car.getName)()` and `car.getName()` are identical statements, there's no intervening boundary. But when you put the assignment in there: `(car.getName = car.getName)()`, then the `()` is applied to the result of the assignment, which is just a function reference with no object associated with it. You can read up on what the assignment statement does in glorious, if turgid, detail [here](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), and how calls occur [here](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3). Brace yourself, it's arcane language. :-)

Comment: **is applied to the result of the assignment, which is just a function reference with no object associated with it**.                           That's explain why these statements: `car.getName = car.getName; car.getName();` outputs Ferrari. Actually, all the tricky thing is about rules of assignment when enclosed with parentheses;) Thanks :)

Comment: @Mik378: (Glad that helped.) Right. The main thing to remember is that function references are just function references, JavaScript doesn't have *methods*. And so unless `bind` or similar is used, `this` is set at the point of the call. The trick in the code you posted is where the point of the call was and what, if anything, was there between that and retrieving the function reference from the object. The answer was that there's an assignment statement in the way, which is where `this` got lost.

Comment: Excellent, I've just started learning ECMAScript and I already love it :) Re-Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Aaah, `this` resolution...Lets take a gander.

```
var toy = {
    log : function () { console.log(this); }
};
toy.log() //logs the toy object
```

So far, it seems like `this` resolution is static: Wherever the method was defined in, that's its `this` value.

But! What if we do this:

```
var sneakyBastard = toy.log;
sneakyBastard(); //logs Window
```

`this` is bound to the object it's called with. In the case of `toy.log`, you called `log` in the context of the `toy` object. But, `sneakyBastard` has no set context, so it's as if you've called `window.sneakyBastard`.

Now let's take a goose (goose? gander? no...) at your expression:

```
(car.getName = car.getName)()
```

...and what does an assignment return? The assigned value, in this case, a function, `car.getName`. We can break this expression into two:

```
var returnedValue = (car.getName = car.getName);
returnedValue();
```

...and from here it's obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `getName` from the context of an object, you're calling it from the context of the return result of the grouping operator *(which in this case there's no context)*.

In JavaScript, when there's no clear context defined, a default is used. The default is...

- the global object when in *strict mode*
- `undefined` when *not* in *strict mode*

Answer (score 1):

You have put your function call parenthesis (`()`) so they call the *result of the expression* `(car.getName = car.getName)` (which is the value (a function) assigned to `car.getName`)